# 32 bit toolchain is used for compilation even though Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64 toolchain is enabled

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, tensorflow, cmake, msbuild

I am trying to compile the TensorFlow CMake build on Windows which requires the 64-bit toolchain to not run out of memory during compilation. However, even though the Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64 toolchain is enabled in the command prompt, the 32 bit toolchain is used for compilation as evident by the Task Manager which shows `MSBuild (32 bit)` and `Microsoft(R) C/C++ Compiler Driver (32 bit)` processes. Consequently the `error: c1060: compiler is out of heap space` is thrown it some point.

This is what I have done so far: To enable the 64 bit toolchain, I open `VS2015 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt`. When configuring CMake, I get the output

```
-- Building for: Visual Studio 14 2015
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24215.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24215.1
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found PythonLibs: C:/Users/kasper/Anaconda3/libs/python35.lib (found version "3.5.2")
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

so CMake seems to have picked up the 64 bit compiler. Futher,
running `cl` in the command prompt gives

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.24215.1 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

I have also tried to run `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall amd64"` prior to configuring CMake but to no avail. The 32 bit toolchain is still used for compilation in the end.

What am I missing?

Comment: Note that unless you somehow fiddled with your VS installation, CMake is able to detect the location of your compiler even from an ordinary `cmd` prompt. So there is no reason for opening the VS prompt, you just have to specify which compiler you want to use to `cmake` or `cmake-gui`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When executing CMake, you must specify that you want it in the 64-bit version:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" [...]
```

Otherwise, in your case, by default it does the same as

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015" [...]
```

and configures it in 32-bit mode.

Comment: Thanks for your input. It got me a bit further. Now I am stuck here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46302725/how-to-pass-cmake-generator-to-a-cmake-external-project

Answer (score 2):

From CMake --help commandline:

```
Visual Studio 14 2015 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2015 project
files.  
Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
```

If you want to build for x64 target, you need to specify the right CMake generator:

```
CMake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" ....
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! oLen was first unfortunately. See my comment to his answer.