# How to pass CMAKE_GENERATOR to a CMake external project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, tensorflow, cmake, msbuild

I am trying to compile the TensorFlow CMake build as an external project on Windows. This requires the 64-bit toolchain to not run out of memory during compilation. However, even though the `CMAKE_GENERATOR` for the top-level project is `Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64`, and this is passed to the external project via the `CMAKE_GENERATOR` variable, the 32 bit toolchain is used to compile the external project.

What I observe: When the build is started, a 64 bit `MSBuild` process spawns to drive the main project as expected. This can be seen in the task manager. When building the TensorFlow external project however, an `MSBuild (32 bit)` process start for the external project. The compiler later fails with the `error: c1060: compiler is out of heap space`.

The CMake code for the TensorFlow external project is

```
ExternalProject_Add(TensorFlow
  GIT_REPOSITORY ${TensorFlow_REPOSITORY}
  SOURCE_DIR ${TensorFlow_SOURCE_DIR}
  SOURCE_SUBDIR tensorflow/contrib/cmake
  BINARY_DIR ${TensorFlow_BINARY_DIR}
  CMAKE_GENERATOR ${CMAKE_GENERATOR}
  CMAKE_ARGS
    --no-warn-unused-cli
    -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=${BUILD_SHARED_LIBS}
    -DSWIG_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=${SWIG_EXECUTABLE}
    -DPYTHON_EXEUTABLE:FILEPATH=${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE}
    -DPYTHON_LIBRARIES:LIST=${PYTHON_LIBRARIES}
    -Dtensorflow_WIN_CPU_SIMD_OPTIONS=/arch:AVX
  UPDATE_COMMAND ""
  DEPENDS ${TensorFlow_DEPENDENCIES}
)
```

The output from the TensorFlow configuration stage is

```
Creating directories for 'TensorFlow'
Performing download step (git clone) for 'TensorFlow'
Cloning into 'TensorFlow'...
Checking out files: 100% (7280/7280), done.
Already on 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
No update step for 'TensorFlow'
No patch step for 'TensorFlow'
Performing configure step for 'TensorFlow'
Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24215.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24215.1
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe -- wor
ks
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Performing Test COMPILER_OPT_ARCH_NATIVE_SUPPORTED
-- Performing Test COMPILER_OPT_ARCH_NATIVE_SUPPORTED - Failed
-- Performing Test COMPILER_OPT_WIN_CPU_SIMD_SUPPORTED
-- Performing Test COMPILER_OPT_WIN_CPU_SIMD_SUPPORTED - Success
-- Found PythonInterp: C:/Users/kasper/Anaconda3/python.exe (found version "3.5.2")
-- Found PythonLibs: C:/Users/kasper/Anaconda3/libs/python35.lib (found version "3.5.2")
-- Found SWIG: C:/Development/build/t/SWIG/swig.exe (found version "3.0.10")
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Development/build/t/TensorFlow-build
```

Then adding `message(STATUS "CMAKE_GENERATOR: ${CMAKE_GENERATOR")` to the top-level TensorFlow `CMakeLists.txt` and running `cmake .` in the `TensorFlow-build` directory gives

```
-- CMAKE_GENERATOR: Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

The value of `CMAKE_GENERATOR` in the TensorFlow external project *is* `Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64`. I also tried to add `-G ${CMAKE_GENERATOR}` to CMAKE_ARGS but to no avail. Task manager still shows `MSBuild (32 bit)` and `Microsoft Compiler/Linker Driver (32 bit)` when the external project starts.

The code can be found here: https://github.com/kaspermarstal/TensorFlowImageFilter.

What am I missing?

Comment: ***What am I missing?*** I believe that the problem is not the generator.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/commit/d079e71c290c3c55a2db5180953daf014a964c25

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_VS_PLATFORM_TOOLSET_HOST_ARCHITECTURE.html

Comment: Your comments led me to https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17005 which suggests to use `-A x64 -T host=x64`. Having reread the TensorFlow docs, using `-A x64` is also what they write. Same result however (now also passing CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM and CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET to external projects). The top-level project is compiled with the 64 bit toolset, the external projects are compiled with the 32 bit toolset.

Comment: It turns out it was `MSBuild` that was still 32 bit. The `Microsoft C/C++ Compiler Driver` itself is now 64 bit and the TensorFlow external project compiles successfully. Thank you for your hint.

Comment: In your case, the issue was not about the generator but in my case it is. The difference in behavior explained here between `CMAKE_GENERATOR` and `-G ${CMAKE_GENERATOR}` helps me to find the right way to use a different generator for my `ExternalProject_Add`.